# How to emulate find_package() to do same as add_subdirectory()? (Modern CMake)

Tags: c++, cmake

My question is greatly related to what they call **Modern CMake**. I've read a lot about CMake trying to get the best practice to avoid anti-patterns.

My project is under development and I don't want to install my library nor having anything being generated outside the repo. ($HOME, /usr/local or wherever)
Everything must stay inside the repository.

I read `add_subdirectories()` using out-of-tree folder is an anti-pattern. I'm looking for a better way of doing what I want.

I have a library and an app under development, each in their own folder. <s>During the development phase, the library shouldn't be treated as a library (.a/.so)</s>.

When I compile the app, I'd like the lib to be built too.

```
.
+-- lib
|   +- CMakeLists.txt
|   +- src
|   |  +- lib.cpp
|   +- include
|   |  +- lib.h

+-- app
    +- CMakeLists.txt
    +- src
    |  +- app.cpp
    +- include
    |  +- app.h
```

- lib/CMakeLists.txt:

```sh
add_library(mylib src/lib.cpp)

# Export the public header files to any future user
target_include_directories(mylib 
  PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include
)
```

- app/CMakeLists.txt: I was thinking using `find_package()` with a `cmake/FindMyLib.cmake`

  - cmake/FindMyLib.cmake should contain the link to `../lib`, in the same way I'd do with `add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib build)`

```sh
list(INSERT CMAKE_MODULE_PATH 0 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

find_package(mylib REQUIRED)
include_directories("${mylib_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

- Is my workflow legit?
- How can I do it?

Why isn't it easier to do such a simple project.. CMake is just a jungle.

Comment: If you want these in separate folders, then I'd suggest treating them like separate projects, especially if you're planning to keep the library separate anyway.  I can't think of a good solution for your requirements that won't just cause more problems down the road.

Comment: Don't I treat them as separate projects already? My requirements seem very easy tho. Single repo, lib and app in two separate folders, treated as different projects.

Comment: "During the development phase, the library shouldn't be treated as a library (.a/.so)."

Comment: I'm surprised that requirement raises problems, I remove it then.

Comment: Since it's one repository, just add a root `CMakeLists.txt` and add both folders.  Link against the library using `target_link_libraries`.  No need for `find_package` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Few notes concerning your "Modern" CMake.

Your include calls are wrong please use:

```
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mylib>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/mylib>  # <prefix>/include/mylib
)
```

i.e. you don't want to see a local path in the install export.
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html

And since you are using target properties, you won't need any `mylib_INCLUDE_DIRS`, simply use:

```
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE mylib)
```

here `mylib` will "forward" its include directories to your app.

Answer (score 0):

You could of course add a `CMakeLists.txt` file to the parent directory of `lib` and `app`

```
project(SomeName)

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(app)
```

To me this seems like the only option to have both mylib and app available as targets in the same project. This allows you to simply use

```
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE mylib)
```

in `app/CMakeLists.txt`.

However there's no need to install the library outside of the repository. Just specify [`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) to be a directory inside the repository and specify a seperate directory for packaging by setting [`CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/variable/CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX.html). In fact this is what cpack does prior to adding all the files to the output file.

**lib/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(mylib src/lib.cpp include/lib.h) # added header here to show up in IDE

# Export the public header files to any future user
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mylib>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)

set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER mylib/include/lib.h)

install(TARGETS mylib EXPORT mylib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib # .lib destination
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib # .so location
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin # .dll location
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include 
)

install(EXPORT mylib DESTINATION mylib FILE mylib-config.cmake)
```

You could build and install the library to a directory inside the repository by executing the following commands starting at the parent directory of `lib` and `app` (assuming linux bash here):

```
mkdir mylib/build
mkdir local_installs
cmake -D "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$(pwd)/local_installs" -S mylib -B mylib/build
cmake --build mylib/build --target INSTALL
```

This allows you to use `find_package` using the config version in app:

```
find_package(mylib REQUIRED
    PATHS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../local_installs/mylib" 
    NO_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH NO_CMAKE_PATH NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH # prevent lookup at location other than local_installs first
    )
```